# Twitter login in Phone Gap for Ios

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new in application development and recently while working in my application which is in PhoneGap (Cordova 2.5) i need twitter login for my app.

I have googled for this and what I got is

"https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Twitter"

but in github all the info is not given so that I can run my app for twitter login .

Is there anyone who could help me to create twitter login in PhoneGap??

Answer (score 0):

Do some reading on OAuth. Implementing OAuth authentication on your own is not that bad. Although, Twitter uses OAuth 1, not OAuth 2, so that might make it a little more tricky. If I had more PhoneGap experience, I could could provide more direct answers, but I've only done native development. Best of luck.